# Web Services with JAX WS-SUN library in WAS 7.0

Tags: java, websphere, jax-ws, endorsed

**CONTEXT OF THE PROBLEM:**

I consume a Web service methods exposed by an institution outside the mine, the web service was generated by JAX WS-SUN.
Implement other web service for domestic consumption of my institution which encapsulates the methods exposed by the outsourcer, use JAX WS-SUN (not IBM), initially had some problems with the recognition of some jar.
Try setting the shared libraries on the server to use the jar with the class loader PARENT_LAST and did not work.
Try reliza with JAX WS-IBM libraries but had no success, so do so with JAX WS-SUN (libraries used by the external service provider)
Then I found a solution using the "endorsed" folder (this folder already existed but was empty) that is in the sdk directory tree included in the WAS 7.0 and copying other jar in the "classes" folder, which are physically located (in my PC):

```
endorsed: E: \ IBM \ SDP \ jdk \ jre \ lib \ Endorsed
jar copied: 
- saaj-api.jar
- Saaj-impl.jar
- Serializer-2.7.1.jar
- Stax-1.2.0.jar
- Stax-ex.jar
- Streambuffer.jar
- Xalan-2.7.1.jar
- XercesImpl-2.9.0.jar
- Xml-apis-1.3.04.jar

classes: E: \ IBM \ SDP \ runtimes \ base_v7 \ profiles \ AppSrv01 \ classes
jar copied: 
- jaxb-api.jar
- Jaxb-impl.jar
- Jaxb-xjc.jar
- Jaxp-ri-1.4.2.jar
- Jaxws-api.jar
- Jaxws-rt.jar
- Jaxws-tools.jar
- Webservices-api.jar
- Webservices-rt.jar
```

To deploy the application using the WAS 7.0 that is included in the RSA 7.5 (Rational Software Architect) which is installed on Windows Server 2003 EE - 32bit. So far so good, do my test query exposed methods and get the expected response

**THE PROBLEM:**

The problem arises when I deploy the EAR to WAS 7.0 that is installed on linux (RedHat) kernel 2.6.18 - 64 bits.

In this case I had to create the folder it was not endorsed directory and put the jar in each directory listed above, which are physically located in:

```
Endorsed: / opt / IBM / WebSphere / AppServer / java / jre / lib / endorsed
classes: / opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/classes
```

Then I do my tests and trace gives the following error:

```
[01/20/2012 9:11:54] ERROR [class: pe.gob.pj.WsBiometriaImpl] error
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com / sun / xml / stream / buffer / Stax / StreamWriterBufferCreator.setCheckAttributeValue (Z) V
 at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest (SecurityClientTube.java: 170)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun (Fiber.java: 598)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun (Fiber.java: 557)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun (Fiber.java: 542)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync (Fiber.java: 439)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process (Stub.java: 222)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess (SEIStub.java: 135)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke (SyncMethodHandler.java: 109)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke (SyncMethodHandler.java: 89)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke (SEIStub.java: 118)
 at $ Proxy158.login (Unknown Source)
 at reniec.ws.AccessWS.loginWSBIO (AccessWS.java: 36)
 at pe.gob.pj.WsBiometriaImpl.loginWSBIO (WsBiometriaImpl.java: 74)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java: 45)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java: 37)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java: 599)
 com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver at $ 1.invoke (InstanceResolver.java: 246)
 com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube at $ 2.invoke (InvokerTube.java: 146)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke (EndpointMethodHandler.java: 257)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest (SEIInvokerTube.java: 93)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun (Fiber.java: 598)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun (Fiber.java: 557)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun (Fiber.java: 542)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync (Fiber.java: 439)
 com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl at $ 2.process (WSEndpointImpl.java: 243)
 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter at $ HttpToolkit.handle (HttpAdapter.java: 444)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle (HttpAdapter.java: 244)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle (ServletAdapter.java: 135)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet (WSServletDelegate.java: 129)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost (WSServletDelegate.java: 160)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost (WSServlet.java: 75)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java: 738)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java: 831)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service (ServletWrapper.java: 1657)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest (ServletWrapper.java: 939)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest (ServletWrapper.java: 502)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest (ServletWrapperImpl.java: 179)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest (CacheServletWrapper.java: 91)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest (WebContainer.java: 864)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest (WSWebContainer.java: 1583)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready (WCChannelLink.java: 186)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination (HttpInboundLink.java: 445)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest (HttpInboundLink.java: 504)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest (HttpInboundLink.java: 301)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete (HttpICLReadCallback.java: 83)
 at
 at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback (AbstractAsyncFuture.java: 217)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions (AsyncChannelFuture.java: 161)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed (AsyncFuture.java: 138)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete (ResultHandler.java: 204)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop (ResultHandler.java: 775)
 com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler at $ 2.run (ResultHandler.java: 905)
 at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool $ Worker.run (ThreadPool.java: 1604)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com / sun / xml / stream / buffer / Stax / StreamWriterBufferCreator.setCheckAttributeValue (Z) V
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.message.SOAPBody.cachePayLoad (SOAPBody.java: 204)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignedMessagePart.writeTo (SignedMessagePart.java: 147)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.crypto.JAXBDataImpl.writeTo (JAXBDataImpl.java: 117)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.Exc14nCanonicalizer.transform (Exc14nCanonicalizer.java: 181)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.Transform.transform (Transform.java: 178)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.Reference.transform (Reference.java: 183)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.Reference.digest (Reference.java: 124)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.Signature.sign (Signature.java: 214)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.dsig.SignatureProcessor.sign (SignatureProcessor.java: 122)
 at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.sign (SignatureFilter.java: 544)
 at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.filter.SignatureFilter.process (SignatureFilter.java: 506)
 at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processWSSPolicy (HarnessUtil.java: 93)
 at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.HarnessUtil.processDeep (HarnessUtil.java: 268)
 at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.processMessagePolicy (SecurityAnnotator.java: 186)
 at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.SecurityAnnotator.secureMessage (SecurityAnnotator.java: 147)
 at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.secureOutboundMessage (SecurityTubeBase.java: 390)
 at
 at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest (SecurityClientTube.java: 167)
 ... 53 more
```

I would appreciate if you could give me some idea of ??the origin of the problem or any way to fix it

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like maybe the endorsed directory you created is not recognized as such.

IBM recommends a different approach in their documentation for WAS 7.0.

[Using a third-party JAX-WS Web services engine](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftwbs_thirdparty.html&resultof=%22Using%22%20%22us%22%20%22third-party%22%20%22JAX-WS%22%20%22Web%22%20%22web%22%20%22services%22%20%22servic%22%20%22engine%22%20%22engin%22)